# Android:Retrieve size of amr audio file

Tags: android, size, audio-recording

I am making an app in which i have to get the **size** of amr file.Any help regarding this will be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: I tried many links but found nothing about how to get size of amr file i have the path of amr recording but now i want to know that can we get size of amr file with the help of its path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As if you have the path just put your path in given code and you will get the length of file in bytes.

```
File file=new File("/sdcard/"+path of the file whose size you want);
long length = file.length();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help and +1 for help